# Make NPM remove module deleted from package.json, ie reflect the state of package.json

Tags: node.js, module, npm, uninstallation, package.json

If I remove a dependency in package.json, is there a command I can run to make NPM delete it from the node_modules directory?

I know I can delete it from NPM directly with

```
npm uninstall <module> --save
```

But I think it would be easier if I could just remove the line from package.json and run a command and NPM would delete it (and/or install whatever I added to package.json). In other words, I want a command to make my node_modules directory reflect the dependencies I set up in package.json.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want a command to make my node_modules directory reflect the dependencies I set up in package.json. Is there any way to do this?

Not yet.  This is functionality that may come in `npm@3` -- you can read the blog post that lays out the plan for `npm@3` dependency calculation here: http://blog.npmjs.org/post/98233700815/multi-stage-installs-and-a-better-npm

At present, the most reliable way to make node_modules reflect exactly what's in your package.json is `rm -rf node_modules ; npm install`, which is usually overkill.

`npm ls` will tell you when a package is installed but not referenced.

Answer (score 5):

Use `npm prune` command to remove the packages previously installed but removed from package.json file.